# MS Access - JOIN using LIKE and AND

Tags: sql, ms-access

**OBJECTIVE**

Develop a Sales Report that outputs a product catalog to showcase new/existing products. Report details include:

- CUSTOMER ID
- CUSTOMER NAME (specific to `CUSTOMER ID`)
- ITEM ID
- STYLE
- INVENTORY COUNT
- DEMAND FORECAST (specific to `ITEM ID` & `CUSTOMER ID`)
- LAST PURCHASE ORDER DATE (specific to `ITEM ID` & `CUSTOMER ID`)

---

**First, a bit of BACKGROUND**

Initially, I developed reports that highlighted a Company's (`COMPANY ID`) historical purchase orders (max(`PURCHASE ORDER DATE`)) for a specific item (`ITEM ID`). However, this quickly failed since *new* products are also apart of the catalog (where there is no history of a `PURCHASE ORDER DATE`). To make matters worse, our company forecasts demand for items (`DEMAND FORECAST`), even if the product is completely new (why this is the case, I have no idea).

**As a result, `CUSTOMER` and `ITEM ID` cannot be directly related (since, sometimes customers shown new products).**

**To make matters worse, a `CUSTOMER` may have multiple `CUSTOMER NAMES` (e.g "Home Depot", "HOME DEPOT ONLINE", etc.)**

---

**APPROACH**

1. Create a table of `Customer IDs`, `Customer Names` (completed)
2. Create a table of `Item ID` and their `Inventory` (completed)
3. Create a table of max(`Purchase orders`) (latest purchase order), including `Customer IDs` and `Item IDs` (completed)
4. Create a table of `Demand Forecasts`, based on `Customer ID` and `Item ID` (completed)
5. **Create a middle table, "Active Catalog" that links `Customer Name` to `Item ID` depending on whether or not we want to showcase certain new/existing products (incomplete)**
6. Link the "Active Catalog" table to "Purchase Order Table" and "Forecast Table", based on `ITEM ID` and **LIKE** `CUSTOMER NAME` (since 1 customer can have multiple variations of a name).

*NOTE: To reiterate, the reason why I have to Steps #3 and #4 is due to the fact that a company can have a purchase order, but no forecasts; or a forecast, but no previous purchase order for each item. As a result, step #5 is required to solidify the link between a `Company ID` and a `Item` and Step #6 is added complexity because our database is way screwed up...*

---

**ILLUSTRATION**
[image: Currently in MS Access]

---

**CODE**

```
SELECT 
  [Active Catalog].[CUSTOMER NAME], 
  [Table - Item and Company Forecasted Sales].[COMPANY ID], 
  [Table - Item and Company Forecasted Sales].ITEM, 
  [Table - Item and Company Forecasted Sales].STYLE, 
  [Table - Item and Company Forecasted Sales].DESCRIPTION, 
  [Table - Item and Company Historic Sales].PRICE, 
  [Table - Item and Company Forecasted Sales].[ON-HAND QTY], 
  [Table - Item and Company Forecasted Sales].[FORECAST QTY], 
  [Table - Item and Company Historic Sales].[LATEST PO DATE] 
INTO [Table - Summary]

FROM ([Active Catalog] 
  INNER JOIN [Table - Item and Company Forecasted Sales] 
      ON ([Active Catalog].STYLE = [Table - Item and Company Forecasted Sales].STYLE) 
      AND ([Active Catalog].[CUSTOMER NAME] LIKE '%' + [Table - Item and Company Forecasted Sales].[CUSTOMER NAME] + '%')) 
  INNER JOIN [Table - Item and Company Historic Sales] 
      ON ([Active Catalog].STYLE = [Table - Item and Company Historic Sales].STYLE) 
      AND ([Active Catalog].[CUSTOMER NAME] LIKE '%' + [Table - Item and Company Historic Sales].[CUSTOMER NAME] +'%')

GROUP BY 
  [Active Catalog].[CUSTOMER NAME], 
  [Table - Item and Company Forecasted Sales].[COMPANY ID], 
  [Table - Item and Company Forecasted Sales].ITEM, 
  [Table - Item and Company Forecasted Sales].STYLE, 
  [Table - Item and Company Forecasted Sales].DESCRIPTION, 
  [Table - Item and Company Historic Sales].PRICE, 
  [Table - Item and Company Forecasted Sales].[ON-HAND QTY], 
  [Table - Item and Company Forecasted Sales].[FORECAST QTY], 
  [Table - Item and Company Historic Sales].[LATEST PO DATE];
```

---

**QUESTIONS**

1. I would like to join a table based on the `ITEM ID` **AND** the relative **likeliness of the `CUSTOMER NAME`** since, as stated, 1 `CUSTOMER ID` has multiple but similar `CUSTOMER NAMES` (e.g HOMEDEPOT, HOMEDEPOT ONLINE). However, my code seems be incorrect. See: `... LIKE '%' + [Table - Item and Company Forecasted Sales].[CUSTOMER NAME] + '%'))` in Code above.

Comment: @sefran2 - shouldn't the use of the '%' wildcard enable me to add zero or more characters around the customer name, effectively making it a LIKE statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow-up:

I created an "Active Product" table to display new/existing products.

Furthermore, I've created a seperate query that has MsgBox prompt, enabling users to search for LIKE terms by following [this tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-parameters-to-ask-for-input-when-running-a-query-c2806d3d-d500-45a8-8507-ec6af351b6ed)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue could be due to the LIKE wildcard used. Try * instead of %.

See [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Examples-of-wildcard-characters-939e153f-bd30-47e4-a763-61897c87b3f4).

Comment: Tried replacing '%' with '*' and still receive a result of zero. Also replaced 'LIKE' with '=' and again, a result of zero :(

Comment: You should also change the '+' to '&'. The concatenation operator in Access is the ampersand.

Comment: Disable your second INNER JOIN and run the adapted query. Does that retrieve any records?